# Clear corresponding column on change

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns which need to correspond with each other. A2-A51 & B2-B51. Column A contains the name, column B contains the date. I am trying to create a on-change event where if a cell within column A is cleared, the corresponding one in the same row is cleared in column B.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
    If Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("A2:A51")) Is Nothing Then
        If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Range("B" & Range("A2:A51").Row).Clear
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("A2:A51")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "" Then
            Range("B" & Target.Row).Clear
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Put it in the code for your sheet.

Comment: Very nice concept with the "KeyCells" and passing in Target as Range. I'll have to look into this further as I am new to on-change events. Thank you.

Comment: I've updated your code a little, no need to take `Target` which is a Range, take it's  address and then define it with `Range(Target.Address)`, just use `Target` . you can also replace `Range("B" & Target.Row).Clear` with `Target.Offset(0,1).Clear`